# How do I navigate backward and forward with React Router v5?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I can refresh my pages, but when I use the back and forward buttons in chrome my app breaks. 
I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: this.props.cars.map is not a function. I'm very new to React Router and I feel like this should be an easy fix.

This is my App component:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import CarsIndex from "../containers/cars_index";
import CarNew from "../containers/car_new";
import CarShow from "../containers/car_show";
import Error from "./error";

function App() {
 return (
  <Switch>
   <Route path="/" component={CarsIndex} exact />
   <Route path="/new" component={CarNew} />
   <Route path="/show/:id" component={CarShow} />
   <Route component={Error} />
  </Switch>
 );
}

export default App;
```

and this is my index.jsx:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import reduxPromise from "redux-promise";
import logger from "redux-logger";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history"; 

import "../assets/stylesheets/application.scss";

import App from "./components/app";

import carsReducer from "./reducers/cars_reducer.jsx";

const initialState = {
 garage: "lenny",
 cars: [],
};

const reducers = combineReducers({
 garage: (state = null, action) => state,
 cars: carsReducer,
});

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const middleWares = composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(logger, reduxPromise));

// render an instance of the component in the DOM
ReactDOM.render(
 <Provider store={createStore(reducers, initialState, middleWares)}>
  <Router>
   <App />
  </Router>
 </Provider>,
 document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This from react router page

v5

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  const { go, goBack, goForward } = useHistory();

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => go(-2)}>
        Go 2 pages back
      </button>
      <button onClick={goBack}>Go back</button>
      <button onClick={goForward}>Go forward</button>
      <button onClick={() => go(2)}>
        Go 2 pages forward
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

v6

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => navigate(-2)}>
        Go 2 pages back
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => navigate(-1)}>Go back</button>
      <button onClick={() => navigate(1)}>
        Go forward
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => navigate(2)}>
        Go 2 pages forward
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

I think 'this.props.cars.map' is not a function mean that car is not an array so map function not call on it.

My advice (but probably out of date) if you 'very new to React Router' not start with redux example.